# Replace elements in an array with their corresponding elements in PySpark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe:

```
+-----+---------------------+
|Index|flagArray            |
+-----+---------------------+
|1    |[A, S, A, E, Z, S, S]|
|2    |[A, Z, Z, E, Z, S, S]|
+-----+---------------------+
```

I want to represent array elements with their corresponding numeric values.

```
A - 0
F - 1
S - 2
E - 3
Z - 4
```

So the output dataframe should look like this:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
|Index|flagArray            |finalArray           |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
|1    |[A, S, A, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
|2    |[A, Z, Z, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I have written a udf in PySpark where I am achieving it by writing some `if else` statements. Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: Is the order of array elements important?

Comment: yes ordering is important. else it would have been simpler

Comment: OK, I thought so too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can simply use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function to loop through each element of `flagArray` array and get its mapping value from a map column that you can create from that mapping using [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#element_at):

```
mappings = {"A": 0, "F": 1, "S": 2, "E": 3, "Z": 4}
mapping_col = map_from_entries(array(*[struct(lit(k), lit(v)) for k, v in mappings.items()]))

df = df.withColumn("mappings", mapping_col) \
       .withColumn("finalArray", expr(""" transform(flagArray, x -> element_at(mappings, x))""")) \
       .drop("mappings")

df.show(truncate=False)
#+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
#|Index|flagArray            |finalArray           |
#+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
#|1    |[A, S, A, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
#|2    |[A, Z, Z, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
#+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in function to map array elements, so here's perhaps an alternative udf, different from yours in that it uses a list comprehension:

```
dic = {'A':0,'F':1,'S':2,'E':3,'Z':4}
map_array = f.udf(lambda a: [dic[k] for k in a])
df.withColumn('finalArray', map_array(df['flagArray'])).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|Index |flagArray            |finalArray           |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|1     |[A, S, A, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
|2     |[A, Z, Z, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @ernes_k I am facing a issue. When I am trying to do a reverse transformation on finalArray column its working. Whereas If i have both Index value as 1 and i am doing a df.groupBy("Index").agg(max("finalArray").alias('flag')) and thentrying reverse transformation on column flag its not working

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `agg(max("finalArray"))`?

Comment: My problem statement is, For all rows having common Index I have to derive an array which will have flags of highest priority on each array index among the rows.

Therefore i am setting the flag priority first with numeric numbers, then I am doing a groupBy with index and finding the maximum value on each array index. once I derive my array i want to revert the no. with actual Flags.

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 3.1+, you could call [`pyspark.sql.functions.transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html) to do the job:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create example DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A S A E Z S S".split(" ")),
    (2, "A Z Z E Z S S".split(" ")),
], ["Index", "flagArray"])

# make mapping column
mappings = {"A": 0, "F": 1, "S": 2, "E": 3, "Z": 4}
mapping_col = F.map_from_entries(F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(k), F.lit(v)) for k, v in mappings.items()]))

# transform DataFrame
df = df.withColumn("mappings", mapping_col) \
       .withColumn("finalArray", F.transform("flagArray", lambda x: F.element_at("mappings", x))) \
       .drop("mappings")
```

Comment: Hey, Can you pls provide the code for dataframe creation as well.

Comment: @PythonLearner added dataframe creation and fixed some typo

Answer (score 0):

After trying out multiple ways, I successfully created a VectorUDT column with DoubleType values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.ml.functions import array_to_vector

def mapper_func(val):
r = []
for i, x in enumerate(val):
    v = str(mapping_dict.get(x, 0.0)) # Default replace with 0.0
    r.append(float(v))        
return r

my_udf = lambda z: mapper_func(z)
label_udf = F.udf(my_udf, T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType()))

df = df.withColumn('finalArray', array_to_vector(label_udf(df.flagArray)))
```

This will work even for values not present in the dictionary/map. Default replace is 0.0

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.1+**

[**`transform`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) is available directly in Python API

```py
d = {"A": 0, "F": 1, "S": 2, "E": 3, "Z": 4}

map_col = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for i in d.items() for x in i])
df = df.withColumn("finalArray", F.transform('flagArray', lambda x: map_col[x]))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-----+---------------------+---------------------+
# |Index|flagArray            |finalArray           |
# +-----+---------------------+---------------------+
# |1    |[A, S, A, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
# |2    |[A, Z, Z, E, Z, S, S]|[0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2]|
# +-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```